# Modular Design Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, modularity

I've started drawing plugs in Java, like connectors using bezier curves, but just the visual stuff.

[image: example]

Then I begin wondering about making some kind of modular thing, with inputs and outputs. However, I'm very confused on decisions about how to implement it. Let's say for example, a modular synthesizer, or Pure Data / MaxMSP concepts, in which you have modules, and any module has attributes, inputs and outputs.

I wonder if you know what keywords should I use to search something to read about. I need some basic examples or abstract ideas concerning this kind of interface. Is there any some design pattern that fits this idea?

Comment: Well the "modules" is not good definition for what you need. Usually that mean a part of bigger system which you can add or remove - like module for sending emails in your cms or something like that. About design patterns - the most of them are not here to actually solve problem, but to make it easier to use/change/move etc., and if it is good or not to use them, it differs based on what you exactly need. You can try to create a "beta" version of your app, the classes and intefaces Java have enough variability and funcionality itself...

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't need any pattern. I thought I would need an Observer round there. I should start with something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Hw66MLc.jpg), where [O] is an OutNode, [I] is an InNode, and the cables between those Connection objects. Something very simple. I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: I would start with simple interface with methods "input, output, process", than you can create classes which implements it. In your main class you should create some type of engine, which will input, output and process all the instances.

Comment: In the order they were created? considering I'm using ArrayLists to store each Connection

Comment: I dont know how exactly your system should work, but yes, in general, storing all items in one list, which type is their ancestor or implementing interface, is good approach - you access all items equally, no matter what they actual type is - it is good for adding new classes, behaviour etc.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're asking for a keyword **real-time design patterns**, overly OOP is often a performance bottleneck to real-time applications, since all the objects (and I guess polymorphism to some extent) add overhead.

Why real-time application? The graph you provided looks very sophisticated,
You process the incoming data multiple times in parallel, split it up, merge it and so on.

Every node in the graph adds different effects and makes different computations, where some computations may take longer than others - this leads to the conclusion, that in order to have uniform data (sound), you have to keep the data in sync. This is no trivial task.

---

I guess some other keywords would be: sound processing, filter. Or you could ask companies that work in that area for literature.

---

Leaving the time sensitivity aside, I constructed a little OOP example,
maybe an approach like that is sufficient for less complex scenarios

```
public class ConnectionCable implements Runnable, Closeable {
    private final InputLine in;
    private final OutputLine out;

    public ConnectionCable(InputLine in, OutputLine out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
        // cable connects open lines and closes them upon connection
        if (in.isOpen() && out.isOpen()) {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        // cable connects output line to input line
        while (out.read(data) > 0)
            in.write(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.open();
        out.open();
    }
}

interface Line {
    void open();
    void close();
    boolean isOpen();
    boolean isClosed();
}

interface InputLine extends Line {
    int write(byte[] data);
}

interface OutputLine extends Line {
    int read(byte[] data);
}
```

Comment: Who said anything about real-time? Nothing to do with it.

Comment: I did, and I stated my reasons in the second and third paragraph.

Comment: And how exactly do your reasons relate to the question?

Comment: From my understanding the image illustrates the configuration via view, and OP now wants to design the according model. If you incorporate the comments, and OPs answers to them, one can assume that he wants to design some kind of synthesizer. But I have to admit the question per se is not very clear, at least it was to me.

Comment: He is drawing plugs. He isn't producing sound. There is no discernable real-time aspect to this question.

Comment: So you're saying it's not about the model - whatever that may be related to - it's about the view/ view model?